# Mysql variable for IN in WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: mysql, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parameterizing an SQL IN clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause)

Is it possible to use a variable in a IN clause to get the wanted results ?

hard-coded example;

```
SELECT 1 FROM `test` WHERE test_name IN ('Test1', 'Test2');
```

Desired solution:

```
SET @test_names = 'Test1, Test2';
SELECT 1 FROM `test` WHERE test_name IN (@test_names);
```

Or is there some other way to achieve this ?

SOLUTION:

```
SET @test_names = 'Test1,Test2';
SELECT 1 FROM `test` FIND_IN_SET(test_name, @test_names);
```

Notice that the @test_names does not have any spaces in it !

Comment: Thanks the link helped me solved it

Answer (score 0):

just another solution. (Got it by trial and error ^^)

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f535e/43)

```
SET @looking_for = "('Test1', 'Test2')";

SET @sql = CONCAT_WS(' WHERE test_name IN ', 'SELECT * FROM test', @looking_for);
PREPARE preptest FROM @sql;
EXECUTE preptest;
```

Comment: Indeed this is another solution, i'll rather use the other one, that one don't have to create hard-coded SQL